# How should I create Hashtable<Key, Value> when I do not care what is stored in Value?

Tags: java

I want to operate over array of integers, and I can solve the problem using `hashtable`. I want to store the ellements of the array as `Key` but for `Value` I really don't care what will be stored there. In such case how should I create my hashtable? My approach is just to set value as 0 for each element like this:

```
    Hashtable<Integer, Integer> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ht.put(arr[i], 0);
    }
```

Is there any convention what should I do in such cases? For example, is it better to set `Value` as `Boolean` and respectively `true` for all inserted elements? Once again, for me it really doesn't matter what will be stored in `Value`. I just want to know what is the best approach in such cases.

Comment: "I want to operate over array of integers, and I can solve the problem using hashtable" - **wut?** Question: Why are you not just using an array?? (`Integer[] arr = new Integer[capacity];`)

Comment: If you need only keys and not values then you're using the wrong data structure. You need a Set instead of a Hashtable.

Comment: If you do not worry about values then Use `HashSet` where you can store the objects

Comment: `Hashtable<Integer, Object> ht = new Hashtable<>();ht.put(arri[],null);`

Comment: @Vogel612, because I need O(1) access to elements by value, not by their index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out by rolfl, a `Hashtable` is a data structure that existed already before the [Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) was introduced. It *might* be considered as an alternative to a `Collections.synchronizedMap`, but the latter gives some additional flexibility.

So the general recommendation can be to *not* use a `Hashtable` in new code, because there are better options now.

---

Most importantly, regardless of whether you use a `Hashtable` or not: You should never **know** that you're using it. Particularly, you should **never** declare your variable to be a `Hashtable`, but always to be a `Map`:

```
// Don't do this!
Hashtable<Integer, Integer> ht = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

// Do this instead (if you don't need synchronized access)
Map<Integer, Integer> ht = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

// Or this, if you need synchronized access:
Map<Integer, Integer> ht = 
    Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
```

Also see [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

---

That being said: It seems like you don't need a `Map` or `Hashtable` at all. From the description, it sounds like you just want to know whether a particular key is contained in the map. This **could** be modeled in different ways. But most likely, this means that you should use a ***`Set`*** instead of a ***`Map`***

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    set.add(arr[i]);
}

// To check whether an integer is contained in the set:
if (set.contains(42)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Hashtable is a horrible data structure to use, even when you want to store a real value. You should be using a HashMap instead of a Hashtable, unless you know exactly why a Hashtable is good for your situation.

Hashtable is a synchronized class, it does not allow null values, and is generally slower and less usable than Hashmap.

So, never use Hashtable when a HashMap will do.

Regardless, for your use case, you likely want to be [using a HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), and just store the values in there. This will give you what you want.